# How to solve Laravel cant connect with mysql through docker

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, docker, docker-compose

Im trying to deploy my laravel app using docker. Then I created docker-compose.yml file and Dockerfile like below.

docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3.7"
services:
    app:
        build:
            args:
                user: sammy
                uid: 1000
            context: ./
            dockerfile: Dockerfile
        image: travellist
        container_name: travellist-app
        restart: unless-stopped
        working_dir: /var/www/
        volumes:
            - ./:/var/www
        networks:
            - travellist

    db:
        image: mysql:8.0
        container_name: travellist-db
        restart: unless-stopped
        environment:
            MYSQL_DATABASE: '${DB_DATABASE}'
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: '${DB_PASSWORD}'
            MYSQL_PASSWORD: '${DB_PASSWORD}'
            MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD: 1
            SERVICE_TAGS: dev
            SERVICE_NAME: mysql
        volumes:
            - ./docker-compose/mysql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
        networks:
            - travellist

    nginx:
        image: nginx:alpine
        container_name: travellist-nginx
        restart: unless-stopped
        ports:
            - 8000:80
        volumes:
            - ./:/var/www
            - ./docker-compose/nginx:/etc/nginx/conf.d/
        networks:
            - travellist

networks:
    travellist:
        driver: bridge
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM php:7.4-fpm

# Arguments defined in docker-compose.yml
ARG user
ARG uid

# Install system dependencies
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    git \
    curl \
    libpng-dev \
    libonig-dev \
    libxml2-dev \
    zip \
    unzip

# Clear cache
RUN apt-get clean && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Install PHP extensions
RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql mbstring exif pcntl bcmath gd

# Get latest Composer
COPY --from=composer:latest /usr/bin/composer /usr/bin/composer

# Create system user to run Composer and Artisan Commands
RUN useradd -G www-data,root -u $uid -d /home/$user $user
RUN mkdir -p /home/$user/.composer && \
    chown -R $user:$user /home/$user

# Set working directory
WORKDIR /var/www

USER $user
```

And when I try docker-compose up, all the containers run with a any error. And also when I run docker-compose ps, it shows like this,

```
      Name                    Command               State                  Ports
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
travellist-app     docker-php-entrypoint php-fpm    Up      9000/tcp
travellist-db      docker-entrypoint.sh mysqld      Up      3306/tcp, 33060/tcp
travellist-nginx   /docker-entrypoint.sh ngin ...   Up      0.0.0.0:8000->80/tcp,:::8000->80/tcp
```

But, when laravel application, tries to connect with mysql, it doesnt happens. And even I cant connect using TablePlus, it shows this.

```
Lost connection to MySQL server at 'waiting for initial communication packet', system error: 10060
```

And sometimes, I get like below,

```
SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'192.168.48.3' (using password: YES)
```

How can I fix this ??

Comment: do you expose port from db (eg. 3306:3306)

Comment: @EduardoHernandez - I only did above things.. How  can I do it ??

Comment: you can add in your docker-compose.yml in db: something like this
ports:
      - 3306:3306
like you have in nginx:

Comment: @EduardoHernandez _ I did this. but, still nothing works..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're networking the services, you only need to `expose` the port `3306/tcp` (this is the default port `mysql` serves). This makes it inaccessible from `0.0.0.0` but accessible from your `nginx` and `app` container.

I have also added the correct volume to persist data (which I am assuming is what you're trying to do). I moved `mysql` to `latest` - feel free to rollback or stick to `8` if you really? need too.

```
db:
  image: 'mysql:latest'
  restart: 'unless-stopped'
  expose:
    - '3306'
  environment:
    - 'MYSQL_RANDOM_ROOT_PASSWORD=true'
    - 'MYSQL_DATABASE=${DB_DATABASE}'
    - 'MYSQL_USER=${DB_USER}'
    - 'MYSQL_PASSWORD=${DB_PASSWORD}'
    - 'MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD=true'
  volumes:
    - 'laravel-database:/var/lib/mysql/'
  networks:
    - 'travellist'

volumes:
  laravel-database:
```

Further reading can be found on the [Docker hub](https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql/) under `mysql`.

Inside your Laravel `.env`, you should connect to the container via its DNS.

```
DB_HOST=db
```

If you want to connect to this container externally, you'll need to bind the port to the server. Do so by replacing `expose` with the following:

```
ports:
  - '3306:3306'
```

Comment: Im getting this `Named volume "laravel-database:/var/lib/mysql:rw" is used in service "db" but no declaration was found in the volumes section.` thing. How can I fix this ??

Comment: You need to put the `volumes: laravel-database` at the end of the file, after your `services`. Please [refer to my open-source example](https://github.com/Kyle-Jeynes/Laravel-Dockerized/blob/main/laravel/docker-compose.yml)

Comment: I used DB_HOST as u said and added this volume.. Now Im getting `SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Temporary failure in name resolution`.. What can I do ??

Comment: Try just using the service name: `DB_HOST=db` - I think the container will resolve that instead. If this works, I will update my answer.

Comment: Now Im getting `SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'192.168.192.3' (using password: YES) `. Is there a way to fix this ?? I have been trying this for now 2 days.. :/

Comment: It is working and your `db` is now exposed as it should be. The issue you have now is your credentials are incorrect. Ensure your `.env` reflect the correct credentials. You shouldn't be using the `root` user.

Comment: Im confused now.. Then what should I do ?? And also I used ports instead of expose..

Comment: Like my example, use the `DB_USER` and do not set it as `root`. This is a reserved user in `mysql` as it is specified on the docker hub documentation (research before you ask). Set it to `sam` or something and then update your Laravel `.env` to have that same user.

Comment: I added a DB_USERNAME as sail and still gets this `SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'sail'@'192.168.240.2'`

Comment: I'm more confused why you keep getting a `/24` address. Are you running a `mysql` server elsewhere which you're hitting instead? Either way, this is a configuration issue. Ensure your credentials are correct and your `docker-compose` has the same credentials that are not `root`. You're better off asking another question if you cannot resolve this, too much has changed and this answers your current question.

Comment: Likely, if you're connecting from this externally (looking at your IPV4), you will need to configure the user to the `0.0.0.0` interface. Your application should have no issue connecting to this service.

Comment: I have no idea... btw I will ask another question regarding this.. Thank you for your help..